# Find first zero bit in a word from right (LSB)

Tags: memory-management, bitmap, heap, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a small slab allocator for my program, however instead of using lists with locking mechanism, After reading a paper on lockless heaps by IBM, i decided to implement something like that. However which GCC intrinsic (ffs/ffz/ctz etc..) would be most efficient and why ?

My most likely target will be ARMv7 and ARMv6 processors with `CLZ` hardware instruction.

I've comeup with something like

```
uint32_t tmp;
uint32_t new_bits;
uint32_t old_bits;

do {
    old_bits = slab->bitmap;
    tmp = <function>(old_bitmap);
    new_bits = old_bits | (1 << tmp);
} while(cpu_atomic_cmpxchg(&slab->bitmap, old_bits, new_bits) != OS_OKAY);

return ((void *) slab->start + (tmp * slab->blksize))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have CTZ then just invert the value and count trailing zeroes:

```
if (x == -1ULL)
    return /* failure? */;
int index = __builtin_ctz(~x);
```

E.g.

```
                                      v
 x = 0000 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111
~x = 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111 0000
index = __builtin_ctz(~x) = 4
```

Comment: but won't count "leading" zeroes of inverted bitmap give me the first unset bit from left ? OOPS, my mistake i wanted it from right, changing question asap.

Comment: Thanks, but are there any hazards i should know of like if bitmap is zero or otherwise undefined cases ?

Comment: The only pathological case is x = 0xffffffff. If you need to handle that case then you can either test for it explicitly or test `__builtin_ctz(0)` to see what it returns.

Comment: Hmm, btw i still don't understand how counting the number of trailing zeroes gives me the first unset(zero) bit in the word, can you explain that, will mark as the answer then.

Comment: We test the *inverted* value, `~x`, so we find the first 1 from the right in the inverted value, which means we've found the first 0 in the original (non-inverted) value. It only takes one instruction to invert a value, so this solution should be two instructions in total.

Comment: That looks OK, except you don't seem to be handling the case where old_bits == 0 in which case index will be same as for the previous iteration of the loop ?

Comment: I *think* that's OK, but the logic is a little convoluted. Test thoroughly !

Comment: ctz(0) is extremely undefined, so you need an `if` statement.